# Redirecting to previous page after registration in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i want to redirect to a previously accessed page right before accessing the registration page after a user has successfully registered themselves. I edited the registration controller as below although i get the following exception View [http:..127.0.0.1:8000.prices] not found. I cross checked my routes and everything is fine. Here is my register controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'phonenumber' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10', 'max:10'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phonenumber' => $data['phonenumber'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the application's registration form.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        if(session('link')) {
            $myPath = session('link');
            $registerPath = url('/register');
            $previous = url()->previous();

            if($previous = $registerPath) {
                session(['link' => $myPath]);
            }else{
                session(['link' => $previous]);
            }
        }else{
            session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
        }
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(session('link')){
            return view(session('link'));
        }
        return view('/');
    }
}
```

I think the issue is most likely to be with the function:

```
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(session('link')){
            return view(session('link'));
        }
        return view('/');
    }
```

I tried replacing `return view(session('link'));` with `return url()->previous();` but there was no luck. I am using laravel 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually with adding view. Instead of `return view(session('link'));` use `return (session('link'));` Same applies to the return outside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

try to use redirect back

```
 return Redirect::back();
```

do not forget to import redirect in controller

```
use Redirect;
```